# ArangoDB as InMemory Database for JUnit Tests in Quarkus

Tags: arangodb-java

I am developing an quarkus rest service with arangoDB. For Testing I would like to use arangoDB as an in memory database like H2.

I could use my arangoDB Windows instance, but would prefer to use an in memory one.

Has anyone done this befor? If someone has examples or tutorials where I can find the needed maven dependencies and how to correctly setup the pom.xml, would be a big help.

During the junit tests I like to create the database/collection and insert test data on each of the test cases, what is quite easy with H2.

thanks Peter

I have already tried google search and the arangoDB Website, but that was not really helpful.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.